# Redirecting to a JSP instead of the JSON response from a REST call

Tags: java, json, rest, jsp

I am working on an assignment to create a simple blog, where a user can ask questions(posts) and answers can be given as comments.
With my limited knowledge on Java, REST and Jquery, I have managed to fetch the list of posts and am displaying them as a table. 
Now whenever a user clicks on any post, he should be redirected to another page where the corresponding comments of the question can be displayed.
I have implemented a REST method in Java which returns the JSON response with the comments relevant to the post_id passed.
So whenever a user clicks on any post, he is redirected to a REST `URL(.../services/comments?postID=1)` and gets following response:

```
[
  {
    "postID": 1,
    "commentID": 8,
    "comment": "These are the answers getting added",
    "commenterID": 7,
    "commentDate": 1442671662000,
    "commentVote": 0
  }
]
```

Here is my JAVA method serving the REST call:

```
    @GET
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    public List<Comments> getUserComments(@QueryParam("postID") Integer postID) {
    Session ses = HibernateUtil.currentSession();
    ses.flush();
    List<Comments> comments = null;
    if(postID != null)
    {
        comments =  ses.createQuery("select c from Comments c where c.postID="+postID+" order by c.commentDate desc").list();
    }

    HibernateUtil.closeSession();
    return comments;
    }
```

What is the "simplest" way to simultaneously redirect to a JSP where I can parse this JSON and display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to redirect the page to jsp.

What you need is a general template (jsp) of the page to display the post and its answers from the json. This page should make an ajax call to get the json for corresponding post (and its answers) and render it in the page.

Now the problem becomes how to do you pass the post id to this page.
You could do this by setting a non-html tag like this. `<post_id id="post_id" value=1>`. After the page is loaded the jquery will this tag (and extract the `value` attribute) to form the url for ajax call.

### Example

Lets assume you have a page to display the list of all posts. This page will look like

```
<a href="post.jsp?post_id=1"> post1</a>
<br>
<a href="post.jsp?post_id=2"> post2</a>
```

Another jsp page to display the post and its comments. Lets call this `post.jsp`. This page should get a parameter `post_id` in the url. This page will set the tag `<post_id>` and use an ajax request to load the corresponding comments from REST url `.../services/comments?postID="+post_id`.

```
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(
    function () {
        //extract the post_id from tag value
        var post_id = $("post_id").attr("value");
        //form the rest url using post_id
        var post_url = ".../services/comments?postID="+post_id;
        $.ajax(
            {
                url: post_url,
                success: function(data, status, jqXHR, json) {
                    json_data = JSON.parse(data);
                    html="";
                    for(var i=0; i<json_data.length; i++) {
                        //Comments rendering logic
                        html+= "<h5>"+json_data[i].comment +"</h5>";
                    }
                    $("#container").html(html);
                }
            }
        );
    }
);
</script>
<post_id value="<%= request.getParameter("post_id") %>" > </post_id>
<div id="container">
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: `<post_id id="post_id" value=1>` placed in the jsp page referred in the url `services/comments`. Also you don't need to redirect using `window.location.href` instead you could simply use hyper link like `"<a herf="services/comments?postID=" + data[index].postID " > "+ post_title + " </a>"

Comment: Thanks for your inputs @shanmuga, but I still did not understand that how `value` attribute can be dynamic in above case? Please note that I have many rows and JSON I mentioned in the question (with postID=1) is just one of the samples.

Comment: I have edited my answer above. Hope the code example helps.

Comment: thanks a lot for your time and effort. This works fine. I was not aware of `request.getParameter("")` , and so wrote a function to extract postID by parsing current window location. But, what you've explained is very clean !!